# How to add software sources and install programs in evolveOS?

Tags: software-installation

I am trying evolveOS which looks in early beta. Firefox is crushing all the time and I don't know yet how to install new programs. I like its concept and want to keep an eye on it, but I need to be able to install new programs.

The default install manager is very limited at this stage.

(Is it based on OpenSuse? Should I follow commands that should work in Openuse?)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Evolve OS is built from scratch and is an independent Linux distribution. We use "eopkg" for package management.

A quick primer is available here: https://evolve-os.com/wiki/Eopkg

Comment: The part that you are on your IRC is not going to be valid for every reader for this answer. Please remove it from your answer as soon as it is no longer valid. We try to keep the answers (and question) free of chit-chat (read [help→tour](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour))

Comment: I'm always available on IRC and it is a valid means of support. My bouncer is permanently connected and one only has to talk to me, or the other members of our community. IMHO offering support hardly constitutes chit-chat.

Comment: Offering support certainly is not an answer or should be part of an answer.

Comment: Be that as it may, nobody is in a better position to help the OP with this than myself, thus it makes sense they use our support channels. That's all I have to say on the matter.

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.